# How do I get a Kendo DatePicker to work inside an MVC Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Index.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_DateFieldPartial", field);
```

_DateFieldPartial.cshtml

```
@model Simplifyed.Enrollment.Web.Contracts.GenericFormField
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "_DateFieldPartial";
}

<div>
@(Model.FieldLabel):@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("datepicker")
    .Value("10/10/2011")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", title = "datepicker", id = "123" })
    .Deferred()
    )
</div>
```

All I get is a text box, nothing to click. When I click the text box, nothing happens.

I am not using the NuGet package, I am only referencing the Kendo.MVC.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your layout did you add

@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()

Like specified on

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring